# Graph API call via axios has trouble with special character encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, microsoft-graph-api

When I search in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/graph-explorer) for users that contain a special character via:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'jörg')
```

that works well and I get a proper result set like:

```
{
...
"displayName": "Jörg XYZ",
"givenName": "Jörg",
...
},
```

Now in my `node.js` project I try to do the same with `axios` via:

```
axios.default.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users?$filter=startswith(displayName,\'jö\')')
```

but I get an **empty** result set.

So I changed the **jö** to **joe** via:

```
axios.default.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users?$filter=startswith(displayName,\'joe\')')
```

and I get only users that really have **Joe** in the name. But I need **Jö**. So what is happening here?

I already tried to set a char-set via:

```
const options = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1'
  }
};
```

without success. What else can I try out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite simple at the end. The only thing I missed was doing an **encoding** on the name before the query is fired:

```
let nameEncoded = encodeURI(name);
axios.default.get(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'${nameEncoded}')`)
```